# How to get Hive table output to multiple excel sheets

Tags: excel, unix, hadoop, hive

I am new in Hadoop.
I have a table in Hive that have my all required data like this:-

```
Table A.
Id description
1.   abc
1.   Abc2
2.   Cdf
2.    Cdf2
2.     Cdf3
3.      Efg
```

Now wanted output from this table to one excel in multiple sheets like

```
Sheet 1 have data of id 1
Sheet 2 have data of id 2
Sheet 3 have data of id 3.
```

There will be there query like - `select * from A where Id = 1`.

I know we can connect Hive through Unix using `hive -S`  or `hive -f` option but in that output will come in one sheet.

Comment: Use JDBC/ODBC... I don't know how you managed to get `hive -e` into an Excel document

Comment: are you wanted, to have each id has there separate sheet dynamically?

Comment: I guess, you wanted that every Id has there own sheet which has all other corresponding data.?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-connect-excel-hive-odbc-driver

Comment: Yes Ankur, U r correct, I wanted each id has there own sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how Hadoop handles this, but I'm guessing yo uhave less than 1M records, right.  Otherwise, Excel is not the right tool for this job.  Just dump everything to 1 single sheet, and run the VBA code that you see from the link below.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win006_4.htm

This example copy all rows with the same value in the first column of the range to a new worksheet. It will do this for every unique value in this column. The sheets will be named after the Unique value.